# "SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid" killing MySQL performance?

Tags: 6, database

My database server's CPU has been pegged for the last two hours and the site is down as a result. Looking at the process list, I see dozens of queries that all begin "SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid," and from my reading, it appears that this should not be a common occurrence  because these queries are very expensive and this could be the source of my problems.

Is it safe to say there is a view or module making a query incorrectly and if so, how can I can track that query down?

Comment: This is a simple query its unlikely that its killing your performance. Install the devel module and make it display the query log by time. https://drupal.org/project/devel

Comment: Yeah, I've installed that and looked at the queries before, but how do I trace those queries back to specific modules or views?

Comment: Some quick searching suggests to me that no such query exists in core at least (though some similar looking ones in the taxonomy and tracker modules). I would suggest updating the title to better reflect what you are asking, which is how to track down the source of a specific query.

Comment: @clg: Devel module shows you what does that query - the second row in the query log, titled "where", gives you the module.

Comment: @AlexeiRayu So it does! My costliest queries are all coming from "execute," which points to https://api.drupal.org/api/function/execute/6 but that page does not exist. Is that typical for the Drupal API? Sorry for all the basic questions, I am very new to Drupal and helping someone who's been having problems for a long time on their own.

Comment: @clg: Can you please post a screenshot of these entries?

Comment: @AlexeiRayu Try http://i.imgur.com/GabY7Yi.png and http://i.imgur.com/WL08HT3.png

Comment: @clg: I think I have enough data to post an answer. As a by-issue, I also see that you are using a domains access module. Having to match all queries against the domain also creates overhead. I suppose, caching will still work under this setup. Would be crazy if it didn't. Why is devel redirecting you to D6 API? Are you running Drupal 6 with dbtng? https://drupal.org/project/dbtng

Comment: @AlexeiRayu Devel is directing to the D6 api because that's what's set in the Devel module. There is a Domains module, but I couldn't tell you why. Is that typically used in a multi-site setup? This one Drupal app is handling something like 6 sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I see, you may be running views, and complex views, that perform complex queries. **execute()** is a database abstraction layer function. I am deducing that you are using views from the image you sent, which lists queries that look like generated by the views module.

Luckily, if my supposition is correct, then your problem can be lifted. When editing the view, you can enable caching. Unless you have a constant flow of new view items, you can make caching time 10, 30, or even 60 minutes. Or more. Making these expensive queries cached will lift the overhead. Also, if you are using panels, you can cache panel panes as well, or whole pages for anonymous users, keeping in mind, that caching on the larger level (page vs a single view) is more preferable.

Comment: This sounds perfect. I just checked the views and Cache is not enabled for any of those that I looked at. I found an option in Tools that tags each query in such a way that I can trace them back to specific views. I REALLY appreciate your help here and have a better idea of how to proceed.